# Group the application within the following time frames

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UserName |  Time Frame    |      No of Applications
Daniel   |  Week to date  | 3
Daniel   |  Month to date | 10
Daniel   | Year to date   |400
```

Please help me get the above format, below is my statement and output.

```
select j.UserName, i.App_Date as "Time Frame", count(*) as "Num. of Applications" 
from tblApplication as i, tblUsers as j 
where i.User_ID = j.User_ID
group by j.UserName, i.App_Date
union
select distinct a.UserName, b.App_Date, count(b.User_ID) 
from tblUsers as a left join tblApplication as b on a.User_ID = b.User_ID 
where b.User_ID is null
group by a.UserName, b.App_Date
```

Output:

```
UserName    Time Frame         Num. of Applications
----------- ------------------ --------------------
Daniel                           3
Daniel  12/31/2012 12:00:00 AM   1
Daniel  1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM     1
Daniel  2/17/2013 10:37:15 AM    1
Daniel  2/18/2013 10:37:15 AM    1
Daniel  2/19/2013 10:37:15 AM    1
Daniel  2/20/2013 10:37:15 AM    1
Daniel  2/21/2013 10:37:15 AM    1
Daniel  2/22/2013 10:37:15 AM    1
```

Comment: given that data, what is your desired output?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer the one on above sql statement

Answer (score 1):

To see the results on separate rows for different date ranges, try:

```
select u.UserName, d.TimeFrame, count(a.User_ID) 
from 
(select dateadd(d, 1-datepart(dw,getdate()), dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0, getDate()), 0)) StartDate, 
        'Week to date' TimeFrame union all
 select dateadd(d, 1-datepart(dd,getdate()), dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0, getDate()), 0)), 
        'Month to date' union all
 select dateadd(d, 1-datepart(dy,getdate()), dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0, getDate()), 0)), 
        'Year to date') d
cross join tblUsers as u 
left join tblApplication as a 
       on u.User_ID = a.User_ID and d.StartDate <= a.App_Date
group by u.UserName, d.TimeFrame
order by u.UserName, max(d.StartDate) desc
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3897/6).

Comment: @user1700401: I have updated my answer to work with SQLServer.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs improvement in several ways.  Learn how to use proper `join` syntax.  The `join` conditions belong in an `on` clause rather than in the `where` clause.  Also, use reasonable aliases for tables.  `i` and `j` don't mean anything.  `a` and `u` make more sense (abbreviations for the table names).

The following puts this logic into three columns for each user:

```
select u.UserName,
       sum(case when date(now() - dayofweek(now())) = date(app_date - dayofweek(app_date)) then 1 else 0 end) as WeekToDate,
       sum(case when MONTH(now()) = month(app_date) then 1 else 0 end) as MonthToDate,
       sum(case when year(now()) = year(app_date) then 1 else 0 end) as YearToDate
from tblApplication a join
     tblUsers u
     on a.User_Id = u.User_id
group by u.UserName;
```

Comment: please use the database that is on this link

Comment: @user1700401: What database? Which link?

Comment: @MarkBannister Bannister please use the database on this link http://www.finchoice.co.za/TestPage.aspx

Comment: @user1700401: Your question is labelled MySQL, but the link you have posted appears to be using SQLServer. Which do you want to use?

Comment: @user1700401: Both MySQL and SQLServer are forms of SQL, but they have different features - the queries that both Gordon and I wrote make use of date-related functions that are specific to MySQL, as that is what you specified in your question. If you are using a different form of SQL, you should amend your question accordingly - our answers will also have to be rewritten.

Comment: @MarkBannister i'm using SQLServer. I'm still new to this sorry